# Show only main values using Google chart

Tags: javascript, svg, charts

I want to use continuous values on my Google Scatter Chart, but in my view I just want the existent values.

Please check this Fiddle below

http://jsfiddle.net/ghu8wt5g/4/

There are ranges of weeks and money, but I just want to see the values of the main variables:

```
var time1 = 52;
var time2 = 63;
var time3 = 36;
var cost1 = 5;
var cost2 = 14;
var cost3 = 17;
```

I drew lines to mark the exactly location of these values.

Is it possible with the native library? Or how can I do this manually editing the svg element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't do this with the library so I manually modified the .svg using vanilla javascript code.